# ASP.NET C# SQL Server Money format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, format, currency

I have a issue I'm developing a webshop but when I have to post the data on to the Payment Gateway I need to money to be like `1,00$` to be 100 but in the SQL Server database it's `1,0000` and when I use the price formatstring `{0:c}` so how do I convert it to 100?

Comment: Why would "1,00$" be converted to 100?

Comment: 'Cos it's a comma not a decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the dollars * 100 to get it to the whole number value.  Do not use the string formatter and you will just have the numeric value.

ie

```
(Price*100).ToString();
```